# What do the K and N in the triangles mean?

Tags: algorithm, block-diagram

This is a block diagram for a detection algorithm later implemented into a circuit.

[image]

Comment: I'd say "the triangles are amplifiers, and K and N are the gain factors", but, to be sure, it'd be better if the source document/article is given in the question.

Comment: @RohatKılıç That's why I was thinking as well, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Or a complex filter....